# slowly changing dimension updating a field in database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have ssis package that loads dim tables.

The structure of `dim-table(id-key,id-bk,id-name,created-date,updated-date)`

Id-bk is a `business key`,created-date is `system-creation date`,

`updated-date`
Is if any changes to `id-name` that updated-date should be considered

So I used a slowly changing dimension tool from ssis.

But I don't understand how to populate the `updated-date`

When the scd tool is. Configure I get a oledb command : so I did this!

`Update dim-table set id-name=?,updated-date=getdate() where id-bk=?`

If package is created on 11/4/2014 then created-date=11/4/2014 if any changes to id-name in staging table the updated date should reflect in updatte-date field which is I am not getting it correctly

Comment: your question seems to be complex to understand, can you please re phrase it..

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do 1st: install the Kimball SCD component from here: http://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/ and use it instead of the built in SCD component. The wizard will make it easier for you to make the distinction between slowly changing dimensions and history dimensions.

have fun.